# Retrieve data from gov website - either via form or directly via the API

Tags: json, api

I am struggling to understand how our local gov website functions.  Specifically the URL https://self.maidstone.gov.uk/service/check_your_bin_day

Beginning to enter a postcode (not mine) such as 'ME15 7HQ' and without submitting the form, a list of addresses is available.

Selecting an address and then selecting 'black bin and food', the website will return a result of 'Your collection date will be FRI 30/07/2021'.  Again without submitting the form.

Running OWASP's ZAP, I can see that data is being submitted and returned as JSON.  The data begins to be submitted as soon as the postcode is being entered.

I'm obviously an amateur but have never seen a site like this.  The purposes of the request to Stackoverflow is that I would like (either via curl or a HTTP request) to be able to submit a postcode and address, and then receive the bin days as relevant.

Is this possible?  If so any pointers please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website uses JavaScript and HTTP requests to dynamically load data.
For viewing those requests, open devtools > `Network`tab, and click on `XHR` button:
[image: Devtools network tab]

Afterwards, try to write postcode into the form. For me, it made request to `runLookup` url. When you click `Preview` tab, you can see the JSON you was mentioning. In this case, you can find the Street addresses (which are then added to next input on website) is on `integration > transformed > rows_data`.

[image]

The devtools have one amazing feature, that will convert the HTTP request to cURL command, you can do it by right-clicking on the request, `Copy > Copy as cURL command`:

[image: copy curl command]

By this way, you can make the whole process, although, from seeing the whole complexity of their API, I don't think it will be that easy, due you probably would need to preserve cookies, and generally follow some steps of requests to get the result (but this doesn't need to be true, it's just my observation).

Comment: Thanks - yeah i saw the cookies, I was going to try and manipulate the expiry if i could get the rest working.  Cheers for the advice.

Comment: @yeleek you're welcome! If you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it as solved, thanks!